# git checkout remote branch if it exist, else create it

Tags: git, git-branch, checkout

I can't be the first one to ask this, but I'm having trouble finding the right search results. These terms are so overloaded.

Eventually I want to make some additions to a remote branch. Remote branch may not exist. So first I clone remote repo, I only have default branch locally. Then:

so far I have:

```
git checkout -b ${BRANCHNAME} origin/${BRANCHNAME} --track || git checkout -b ${BRANCHNAME}
git add ...
git commit -m "new stuff"
git push origin ${BRANCHNAME}
```

Is there a nicer way to do the first line?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the local branch already exists (and perhaps is different from the remote tracking branch)?

Comment: I wont have a local clash, I added some detail to the question.

Comment: You might want to do a fetch before you start your command.
Also an easier approach might be: 1. fetch, 2. create and switch branch, 3. update remote to origin branch, 4. `git reset --hard {u}`. If step 3 fails your script should fail but you have a new branch (I think), otherwise step 4 moves your branch to where it is supposed to be in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

All branches must have a starting point; your sequence:

- attempt to create branch B at origin/B with origin/B as upstream;
- if that fails, create branch B at HEAD with no upstream

can be rewritten as:

```
if start=$(git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/${BRANCHNAME}); then
    extra="--track origin/${BRANCHNAME}"
else
    start=HEAD
    extra=
fi
git checkout -b ${BRANCHNAME} ${start} $extra
```

(or the equivalent with `git switch -c` as the final command).  But I don't think it can be made any *shorter* than the two-step `||` variant you already have.

Using the `if ... then ... else ... fi` sequence, you can add `--quiet --verify` to the `rev-parse` step and avoid generating error messages, and of course you can also set additional variables as desired so that you can make or early-encode future tests (e.g., decide whether you want to use `git push -u` for instance).